# Sendbird chat SDK for Android not showing the last seen at message in the 1-1 channel header

Tags: android, sendbird, chatsdk

I'm using the sendbird chat sdk for my application. It's not showing the last seen at message in the one-to-one channel header. I have also used this method .setUseLastSeenAt(true) in the channel builder to show the last seen. But still it's not showing the last seen message in the channel header.

I have attached here a web image to visualise my issue due to my application privacy.
[image]

I'm using these version of sendbird chat sdk

`implementation 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-android-sdk:3.0.170'`

`implementation "com.sendbird.sdk:uikit:2.1.7"`

And also the method setUseLastSeenAt() is deprecated. I guess so only it is not showing the last seen message. I have also need to know the alternative method for setUseLastSeenAt()?

Please anybody guide me. I don't have much knowledge in sendbird chat sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself.

I have checked this scenario by degrading sendbird version as  "com.sendbird.sdk:uikit:1.2.2" then the last seen functionality is working fine.

In the newer version of sendbird chat sdk's setUseLastSeenAt() method is deprecated. So that functionality will no longer works.